# Specific HTML tag into button

Tags: html

i am working on my html php game and  i have a button design what do not contain button HTML tag. But i want to give it a button functionality.

Here is HTML code of button what works and do a function to reset time for specific amount of game gold.

```
<form action="game.php?page=buildings" method="post" class="build_form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="queuetype" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="fast">
                        <button type="submit" class="build_submit onlist tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Price : {if $need_dm<10}{10}{else}{pretty_number($need_dm)}{/if}"  style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
                            <img src="./styles/images/arrowTG.png" alt="" width="16" height="16">
                        </button>
                </form>
```

And here is my new button style witch i need to apply the same function as i have set for the button before this.

```
<tr class="data">
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <a class="build-faster dark_highlight building disabled">
                        <div class="build-faster-img" alt="Reset time"></div>
                        <span class="build-txt">Reset time</span>
                        <span class="dm_cost overmark">{if $need_dm<10}{10}{else}{pretty_number($need_dm)}{/if} AM</span>
                        <span class="order_dm">Purchase with gold</span>
                        </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
```

Can someone please tell me what should i do in my case and is it even possible ? 
Or i need to use only button tag ?

Comment: You **should** use a `<button>`. Apply CSS as needed to make it look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

For semantic reasons (which help a lot of users who rely on screen readers and other assitive technologies), you really should use a `<button>`, but you can do what you want by simply applying a `click` event handler to the "fake button" and in that handler, you manually call the `submit` event of the form.

As a side note, you should definitely not be using a `table` for this. Tables are for tabular data rendering, not for layout.

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var fakeSubmit = document.getElementById("fakeSubmit");
fakeSubmit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  form.submit();
});
```

```css
#fakeSubmit {
  border:1px solid #a0a0a0;
  border-radius:1px;
  padding:2px 5px;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#fakeSubmit:hover, #fakeSubmit:active {
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<form action="game.php?page=buildings" method="post" class="build_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="queuetype" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="fast">
  <button type="submit" class="build_submit onlist tooltip" 
          data-tooltip-content="Price : {if $need_dm<10}{10}{else}{pretty_number($need_dm)}{/if}"  
          style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
     <img src="./styles/images/arrowTG.png" alt="some image" width="16" height="16">
  </button>
  
  <div id="fakeSubmit" class="build_submit onlist tooltip" 
          data-tooltip-content="Price : {if $need_dm<10}{10}{else}{pretty_number($need_dm)}{/if}"  
          style="float: right; line-height: 18px; margin-right: 13px;">
     <img src="./styles/images/arrowTG.png" alt="some image" width="16" height="16">
  </div>
  
</form>
```